# Get default value from a select in a query

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Im kinda having troubles learning Linq, people say its not soo hard to learn who already know something about Sql, but im still having troubles, basicly i have a table where i have a expend or a earning, im having troubles when i search between 2 dates some values to do statistics i know that happen, cause sometimes when i search between 2 dates i just have a expense and not a earning and in the query he has no idea what he should do, so how can i put default values for all the atributes inside the select?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string dataInicial, string dataFinal)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var queryDefault = db.SaldoUtilizadores.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId)
     .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationUserId)
     .Select(x => new
     {
         biggestValor = x.Max(y => y.valor),
         lowestValor = x.Min(y => y.valor),
         expenses = x.Where(y => y.valor < 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
         earnings = x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
         lowestDate = x.Where(y => y.valor == x.Min(z => z.valor)).Select(y => y.data).FirstOrDefault(),
         biggestDate = x.Where(y => y.valor == x.Max(z => z.valor)).Select(y => y.data).FirstOrDefault()
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

i already searched a lot and didnt find a concret answer if you guys can help me i appreciate.

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is the problem with your query - runtime exception, incorrect result, etc.?

Comment: the problem is when i select 2 dates in the view that just contains the expense in the table cause it is < 0, the earning dont exist, i want to set the value to 0 when that happen inside the query

Comment: Doesn't `x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Sum(y => y.valor)` do that?

Comment: no, cause x.Where(y => y.valor > 0) doesnt exist in this case, and when it doesnt exist i want to give a default value

Comment: That's exactly what it does - `Sum` of not existing is 0(zero), no? Again, are you getting exception and if yes, what's the exception?

Comment: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Where(condition).Sum(selector)` which generates exception when the result of `Where` is an empty set, you can use one of the following constructs:

(A) `Where(condition).Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()`:

```
expenses = x.Where(y => y.valor < 0).Select(y => y.valor).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
earnings = x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Select(y => y.valor).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
```

(B) `Where(condition).Select(({nullable type})selector).Sum() ?? 0`:

```
expenses = x.Where(y => y.valor < 0).Sum(y => (decimal?)y.valor) ?? 0,
earnings = x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Sum(y => (decimal?)y.valor) ?? 0,
```

(C) `Sum(condition ? selector : 0)`:

```
expenses = x.Sum(y => y.valor < 0 ? y.valor : 0),
earnings = x.Sum(y => y.valor > 0 ? y.valor : 0),
```

Comment: Well i tryed to change on the model to int? and decimal?, but it didnt work :S you know why?

Comment: You don't have to change the model, only the query. From the exception you posted the `valor` property should be `decimal`, right?

Comment: solved with your solution :D thanks why simple things is soo complicate with Asp.net :S

Answer (score 0):

from your problem what I perceived is that you are trying to group the values based on userid.

you can use x.DefaultIfEmpty() according your need.

Comment: i changed my query, forgot to poste my last 1, the problem occurs when there is no expense or no earning between the 2 dates

Answer (score 0):

```
 expenses = ((x.Where(y => y.valor).Sum(y => y.valor))==null ||(x.Where(y =>y.valor).Sum(y => y.valor))<0)?0:x.Where(y => y.valor).Sum(y => y.valor)
```